# Saving the text on current opened page without using urlopen

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I'm fairly new to python, and trying to automate something for my dad as a project. I'm trying to save only the text on a opened page without using urlopen, my current code will open a page for me but I cant figure out how to download only the pages text, and the site prevents you from directly opening the url with something like urllib.
This is my current code which opens the file.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/OtcDownload"
chrome_path = "C:\\Users\\derpe\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(url)

#bypass user agreement
agree = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-warning']")[0]
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
agree.click()

#open non-ats page
nonats = driver.find_element_by_link_text('OTC (Non-ATS) Download')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
nonats.click()

#open download page
downloadats = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/icon_download.png']")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
downloadats.click();
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

##not working
#bs get text with url
html = 'https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/assets/download.html'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(html))
print(soup.get_text())
##returns HTTPError: Forbidden
```

The first portion of my code was meant to get pass the terms of use agreement page and open the document, but how do I then use that page in beautiful soup? my last three lines are my attempt to get the text directly from the url, but it doesnt work because of the site and the user agreement.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the element(s) which contain the text you want, using Selenium?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should do a call to `implicitly_wait` once and before you attempt to find elements.

The problem seems to be that you need to pass a `User-Agent` header for your request. The actual text returned is pure JavaScript, which ends up loading the page content (I have printed this out), so the return value form calling `get_text` is just blank lines:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/OtcDownload"
chrome_path = "C:\\Users\\derpe\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(url)

#bypass user agreement
agree = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-warning']")[0]
agree.click()

#open non-ats page
nonats = driver.find_element_by_link_text('OTC (Non-ATS) Download')
nonats.click()

#open download page
downloadats = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/icon_download.png']")
downloadats.click();

#bs get text with url
url = 'https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/assets/download.html'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
headers = { 'User-Agent' : user_agent }
req = Request(url, headers=headers)
resp = urlopen(req)
html = resp.read().decode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print(soup.get_text())
print(html)
driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="google" content="notranslate" />
    <script>
      var welcomeMessage = 'Please wait';

      window.onload = function()
      {
        if (!window.opener)
        {
          document.body.innerHTML = 'No data found';
        }
        else if (window.opener.downloadCache)
        {
          document.body.innerHTML = window.opener.downloadCache;
        }
        else  
        {
          document.body.innerHTML = welcomeMessage;
          console.log(document.body.innerHTML.substr(0, welcomeMessage.length));
          loading();
        }
      }

      function loading()
      {
        if (document.body.innerHTML.substr(0, welcomeMessage.length) == welcomeMessage)
        {
          document.body.innerHTML += '.';
          setTimeout(loading, 500);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

So you should be trying to load the final page using selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/OtcDownload"
chrome_path = "C:\\Users\\derpe\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)

driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get(url)

#bypass user agreement
agree = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-warning']")[0]
agree.click()

#open non-ats page
nonats = driver.find_element_by_link_text('OTC (Non-ATS) Download')
nonats.click()

#open download page
downloadats = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/icon_download.png']")
downloadats.click();

#bs get text with url
url = 'https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/assets/download.html'
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
print(soup.get_text())
driver.quit()
```

Prints:

```
No data found
```

**Comment**

If you look at the JavaScript returned in the first version of the source, you will see:

```
    if (!window.opener)
    {
      document.body.innerHTML = 'No data found';
    }
```

See [Window.opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener). If you just load the page 'https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/assets/download.html' with `driver.get` as is done in the second source code, `window.opener` will be `null` and that is why you see `No data found`. It seems you are meant to get to this page by clicking on a link that is on a previous page you have loaded.

Comment: I have updated the answer that attempts to explain the 'No data found' result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because then you click the download button, it opens it in a new tab, while the driver is still on the previous tab.
So you have to first switch the tab and then extract the data in the `pre` tag of the page.

The following code will do this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

url = "https://otctransparency.finra.org/otctransparency/OtcDownload"
chrome_path = "C:\\Users\\derpe\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get(url)

#bypass user agreement
agree = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//button[@class='btn btn-warning']")[0]
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
agree.click()

#open non-ats page
nonats = driver.find_element_by_link_text('OTC (Non-ATS) Download')
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
nonats.click()

#open download page
downloadats = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@src='./assets/icon_download.png']")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
downloadats.click();
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

# switch the tab
driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# extract the text in the pre tag
print(driver.find_element_by_tag_name("pre").text)
```